# How to fill a numpy array with a C function located in DLL?

Tags: python, numpy, dll, ctypes

I have a DLL written in C:

```
void fill(int* a) {
    a[0] = 2;
    a[1] = 3;
    a[2] = 5;
}
```

What I want to do is to create a numpy array that contains the numbers written into `a`.

I tried this:

```
import ctypes

_dll = ctypes.CDLL("mydll.so")

type_ = np.int32

bf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(3 * np.dtype(type_).itemsize)
_dll.fill(bf)
a = np.frombuffer(bf.value, dtype=type_)

print(a)
```

It gives the error:

```
    a = np.frombuffer(bf.value, dtype=type_)
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

What is wrong with my python code?